# ajax post method showing 500 internal server error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I a trying to make ajax call to controller to save data, but it showing error in network. my jquery is:

```
    $('document').ready(function(){
      $('#getype th button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var a = $(this).val();
        var b = $(this).text();
        $.get("{{url('gettypes')}}",{id:a}, function(data){
        $('#sample').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                drawRow(data[i]);
            }
            function drawRow(rowData) {
                var row = $("<th />")
                row.empty();
                $("#sample").append(row);
                row.append($("<button id='type' class='btn btn-info' value='"+ rowData.ty_id +"'>" + rowData.ty_name + "</button>"));                
            }            
            $('#sample button').on('click', function(e){
              e.preventDefault(); 
              var c= $(this).val();
              var d = $(this).text();
              $.get("{{url('getdish')}}", {id:c},function(data){
                $('#dishes').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  drawRow(data[i]);
                }
                function drawRow(rowData) {
                    var row = $("<th />")
                    row.empty();
                    $("#dishes").append(row);
                    row.append($("<button id='dish' class='btn' value='"+ rowData.item_id +"'>" + rowData.item_name + "</button>"));                
                }
                $('#dishes button').click(function(){
                  var e = $(this).val();
                  var f = $(this).text();
                  $.post("{{url('postdata')}}",   {cname:b,cid:a,tname:d,tid:c,did:e,dname:f}, function(data){
                console.log(data);
              });
            });
          });
        });
    });
  });
 });
```

my route:`Route::post('postdata','OrdertController@postdata');`

and my controller:

```
public function postdata(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    echo $data;
}
```

what is the problem exactly as I am new in laravel as well as ajax?? thanks.

Comment: please post what you've tried

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: You're showing client-side code, but you should investigate server-side (Laravel) code, to find `500 internal server error` cause..

Comment: As @MarcoS and the error suggests, it is an internal server-side error. That means the error occurred in your server script.

Comment: can you share your debugger error screen shot ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to Laravel!

You need try to change this to the laravel dump method:

```
public function postdata(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    {{ dump($data) }}

    //return $data;
}
```

I think that the problem is the way you use the function, most functions in Laravel needs to return data, you're trying to echo $data.

If you're try to `{{ dump($data) }}` (this will echo all the data inside a variable) it will show you all the `$data` and after that you can comment out `return $data;`.

---

Hope this works!

More information at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers